# Better way to display list of categories

Tags: javascript

I need to display a list of category links, like so:

Category 1, Category 2, Category 3

I've got it working already but the code seems pretty repetitive and a bit of a mess, I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

This is what I've got so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data['categories'].length; i++) {
    var comma = document.createTextNode(', ');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', '#journal__category--' + data['categories'][i]['url_title'] );
        link.setAttribute('class', 'js--page__link');
        link.innerHTML = data['categories'][i]['category_name'];

        document.getElementById('js--journal__categories').appendChild(link);
        if( (i + 1) != data['categories'].length ) {
            document.getElementById('js--journal__categories').appendChild(comma);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I might try to clean things up:

- refer to object properties without bracket notation where possible
  e.g. `data.categories.length`
- create a loop variable for the current category, which allows you to reference it nicely without `data.categories[i]`

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
      var category = data.categories[i];
  }
  ```
- don't look up the container on every iteration, move that outside the loop:

  ```
  var container = document.getElementById('js--journal__categories');
  for (...loop...) {
      ...create your node...
      container.appendChild(link);
  }
  ```
- same for creating the comma node, create it outside the loop.
- you don't need to wrap `i + 1` in parenthesis, and this is just my preference, but you should be consistent with spaces. You could also use `<` instead of `!=` which is more consistent with the for loop. (These are fairly minor nits)

  ```
  if (i + 1 < data.categories.length)
  ```
- Why are you using double dashes and underscores in your element IDs?
- Comments are helpful to explain what your for loop and if statement is doing, since it's probably easier/quicker to understand the comment than figure out the for loop.
- Maybe I'm getting overkill at this point, but a way to write really descriptive, easy to read code is to break it into functions whose name makes sense:

  ```
  function createCategoryElement(name, url_title) {
      ...create your anchor element here...
      ...set its attributes and content, etc...
      return element;
  }
  ```

I ended up with something like this:

```
var data = {
  categories: [
    {name: 'one', url_title: 'oneUrl'},
    {name: 'two', url_title: 'twoUrl'}
  ],
};

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var comma = document.createTextNode(', ');

function createCategoryElement(name, url) {
  var urlBase = '#journal-category-';
  var cssClass = 'js-page-link';

  var el = document.createElement('a');
  el.setAttribute('href', urlBase + url);
  el.setAttribute('class', cssClass);
  el.innerHTML = name;
  return el;
}

// Create HTML elements for each category and append them to the DOM.

for (var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
  var category = data.categories[i];
  var categoryElement = createCategoryElement(category.name, category.url_title);
  container.appendChild(categoryElement);

  // Join categories with a comma
  if (i + 1 < data.categories.length) {
    container.appendChild(comma);
  }
}

        for (...loop over categories...) {
            ...
            var categoryElement = createCategoryElement(category.name, category.url_title);
            container.appendChild(categoryElement);

            if (i + 1 < data.categories.length) {
                containenr.appendChild(commaElement);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, your way definitely seems a lot cleaner. The reason I'm using double -- & __ is because it's a one page site with content pulled in with Ajax so it's kind of a naming structure. `journal` Tells me it's the blog, `__category` Tells me it's a blog category and they `--categoryURL` Tells me the actual category. This also makes everything bookmarkable.

Comment: Cool, if that naming scheme works well for you, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn´t look all too repetitive to me, I see no obvious duplication.
You could extract a local variable or two to make the naming more explicit and to not query for the same element twice.
That would however be a tradeoff between function size and readability. Also you see a few references to the `link` variable in one place, this indicates that this could be pulled into its own function.

```
/**
 * Build a link for a category
 * @param category
 * @return DomNode
 */
function linkForCategory(category) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '#journal__category--' + category['url_title']);
    link.setAttribute('class', 'js--page__link');
    link.innerHTML = category['category_name'];

    return link;
}

for (var i = 0; i < data['categories'].length; i++) {
    var comma = document.createTextNode(', '),
        journal_categories = document.getElementById('js--journal__categories');

    var link = linkForCategory(data['categories'][i]);
    journal_categories.appendChild(link);

    if ( (i + 1) != data['categories'].length ) {
        journal_categories.appendChild(comma);
    }
}
```